What is this female voice sound commonly heard on police radios in U.S. action movies?
I usually watch action movies filmed in the U.S.A. In many scenes where the police arrive, I hear this female voice on the police radio.
You can listen to it here (just a heads-up: the HTTPS error is due to a self-signed certificate) or on this Vocaroo link. The volume voice is a little low, sorry (but the male voice at the end is loud). Another audio from another movie (Relentless 2 at minute 19), same voice. In the second audio, the quality is more clear. I have tried to convert audio to mp3 using this app but translate bad in "And it's time for me to go." (sic!)
Anyone know what this voice means? And also what she said? I've also heard it in the game SimCity 3000 when creating police stations.

@user182601 The OP is pointing out the female voice on the police radio that you hear just before the male voice. It's at a lower volume, so you might not have caught it.

This question is related to this one, also about that clip used in Sim City 3000: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19768/why-do-movies-tv-use-this-police-radio-clip-over-and-over?rq=1

This question is similar to: Why is this police radio clip with a female voice used over and over in movies and TV shows? If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I agree that it appears to be a duplicate of this question - I've re-opened and re-closed as a duplicate to make that clear.  As galacticninja states, if your question is not a duplicate, please edit and make it clear how it is different.
